# Tress DSA (Problem while running the code)

Tags: python, binary-tree

I am trying to find out the top view of a binary tree. The code is running correct on the custom test case but it shows different output on the same input whenever I tried to submit it. The platform is gfg.

I have tried the following code and it is running correctly for most of the test cases.

```
    def topView(self,root):
        
        # code here
        
        map = defaultdict(list)
        queue = [[root , 0]]
    
        while queue:
    
            top , dim = queue.pop(0)
            if not map[dim] : 
                map[dim] = top.data
            
            if top.left:
                queue.append([top.left,  dim - 1])
            if top.right:
                queue.append([top.right,dim + 1])
    
        
        map = dict(sorted(map.items()))
        ans = []
        for key in map:
            ans.append(map[key])
        return ans
```

Comment: Please define “top view” with examples, and the test cases you’re having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing the GeeksforGeeks Python version for running individual tests (before submitting) is 3.7.17, but the version used to test your code when pressing Submit, is 3.5.2

This is crazy, but it explains why your code fails the tests being run *on submission*. Before 3.6 Python didn't guarantee a dict traversal order, and your code relies on insertion order when it does `map = dict(sorted(map.items()))`. But before 3.6 this is useless, as the order of `for key in map` still is undetermined after that recreation of the dict.

The fix is easy. Just don't recreate a dict at the end, but iterate the sorted pairs you get from calling `sorted`:

```
    ans = []
    for key, val in sorted(map.items()):
        ans.append(val)
```

NB: this is not the most efficient solution, but it is good enough to pass the tests.